# Element type in xsd is referring its own Complex type

Tags: soap, xsd, schema, xsd-validation, complextype

I have xsd like this -

```
   <xs:complexType name="ChoiceListItem">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="childChoices" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="tns:ChoiceListItem"/>
     <xs:element name="name" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xs:element name="stringValue" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xs:element name="integerValue" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
```

Here you can see that my ***childChoices type is ChoiceListItem under which it is defined***. Here is my Java class -

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)  
@XmlType(name = "ChoiceListItem", propOrder = {
    "childChoices",
    "name",
    "stringValue",
    "integerValue"
})  
public class ChoiceListItem {

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected List<ChoiceListItem> childChoices;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String name;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String stringValue;
    @XmlElement(required = true, type = Integer.class, nillable = true)
    protected Integer integerValue;
```

When I run it in SOAPUI it did not display the childChoices value but displays the other three items. Here is my output response -

```
  <ns3:getChoiceListItemsResponse xmlns:ns3="http://getservice.service">
     <getChoiceListItemsReturn>
        <items>
           <ChoiceListItem>
              <name>AD SERVICE</name>
              <stringValue>AD SERVICE</stringValue>
              <integerValue xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
           </ChoiceListItem>
```

I guess xsd is not defined properly..Can somebody please help me in defining correct xsd in which sequence element type refer to same Complex type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by making changes into my xsd

```
<xs:complexType name="ChoiceListItem">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="childChoices" nillable="true" type="tns:ChoiceListItemArray"/>
     <xs:element name="name" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xs:element name="stringValue" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xs:element name="integerValue" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="ChoiceListItemArray">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="ChoiceListItem" nillable="true" type="tns:ChoiceListItem"/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
```